# Identify single touch vs move touch on Android

Tags: android, controls, touch

I'm developing a game with 2 functions one is called singleClick() and the other 
moveClick(float dx, float dy)

singleClick() is called from MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

moveClick() is called from MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE (where dx = x- previousX)

My problem: If I try a move action with my finger, the single click is also called. The opposite is also the same, when I single click something with my finger, the moveClick() is called.

I can handle the moveClick() being called at single click but the singleClick() calls when player is moving really screws up my game controls.

How can I know which is which??

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this may have something todo with consuming the touch events. In your onclick listener keep in mind that if you return true that signals you have consumed the event, if you return false that event will continue to fall through and trigger the next listener.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't want to call singleClick() when the player is moving where he touches, then you can't call singleClick from ACTION_UP, because ACTION_UP gets called each time. Maybe add a flag that keeps track of whether its a move event. If the total euclidean distance, sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) > threshold, then change the flag isMove to true. If the total distance is less than that threshold, then call singleClick() in your ACTION_UP.

You might also want to think about timing how long the touch event is, or the total absolute distance (i.e. if someone draws a circle and comes back to the first point, my previous method would register as a single click). Think about how you want the flag to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for an elegant solution, maybe something built-in with android development.. but I guess there is none so I took Benoir's advice and wrote this very not-elegant code (which seems to work well enough)

```
long millisLastTouch=0, millisDif,millisStartTouch=0;
final long minMillisSm = 200, minMillisBig = 300;
boolean isMove = true;


public void run(){//my main thread/loop
    .....
        millisDif = System.currentTimeMillis() - millisLastTouch;
        if (!isMove && millisDif>minMillisBig)  {
            G.currentScreen.singleClick(mPreviousX,mPreviousY);
            isMove = true;//to prevent multiple single clicks
        }
   .....
   }//end of main loop




public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float x = e.getX();     float y = e.getY();         
    switch (e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:       {       }//do nothing

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
        mPreviousX = x; mPreviousY = y;     }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
        boolean newAction;
        millisDif = System.currentTimeMillis() -  millisLastTouch;
        if (millisDif> minMillisSm) {
            newAction = true;
            millisStartTouch = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } 
        else newAction = false;

        millisLastTouch = System.currentTimeMillis();   

        millisDif = System.currentTimeMillis() -  millisStartTouch;
        if (newAction == false && millisDif > minMillisSm){
            float dx = x - mPreviousX;  float dy = y - mPreviousY;
            G.currentScreen.clickMove(x,y,dx,dy);
            isMove = true;
        }
        else isMove = false;        

        mPreviousX = x; mPreviousY = y;
    }   
    }//switch
    return true;
}//onTouchEvent
```

It's time-based only, not distance. If the user touches screen for enough time it will translate as a move action. Otherwise, it remembers the x and y position and will call singleClick() from the main thread